# LINQ statement to find the max amount days using datetime

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ statement that will give me the max number of days between a beginning and an end date.

So I have this statement that gets all the closed issues:

```
var issuesClosed = whseTasks.Where(t => t.CompDate != null);
```

From this list of issues I want to find the max number of days between each record's given issue.StartDate and issue.EndDate and select the record with largest number of days.

EX:

1 | issue.StartDate = 7/3/2014 | issue.EndDate = 7/5/2014   = 2 days

2 | issue.StartDate = 7/1/2014 | issue.EndDate = 7/5/2014   = 4 days

3 | issue.StartDate = 7/1/2014 | issue.EndDate = 7/6/2014   = 5 days

I want to select record 3 because it has the highest number of days.

Comment: is this `linq to sql` ?

Comment: Realize that what you are asking for is a [Non-Sargable query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  This will use no indexes and run over every single record.  Keep in mind your user experience if this is for an end user.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I've been telling people this for a long time, but never knew the term "sargable".  Thanks for expanding my vocabulary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var issues = new[]
{
    new Issue { StartDate = DateTime.Now, EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) },
    new Issue { StartDate = DateTime.Now, EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(12) },
    new Issue { StartDate = DateTime.Now, EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) }
};

var theIssue =
    issues.OrderBy(issue => (issue.StartDate - issue.EndDate).TotalDays)
          .First();
```

Comment: If there is LINQ to SQL involved, I'm not sure whether the date-time subtraction will work. If it doesn't, it should be possible to do something like `issues.Select(_ => new { _.StartDate, _.EndDate }).ToArray()`, and then continue from that in-memory collection.

Comment: Would this actually work when executed though? Not sure if the LINQ provider would be able to translate TimeSpan

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the record with the biggest difference between the two dates should do the job

```
whseTasks.Where(t => t.CompDate != null)
         .Max(x => x.EndDate - x.StartDate);
```